# Sublime tmLanguage file and sublime-settings file

Tags: editor, text-editor, sublimetext, textmatebundles, sublimetext2

I have two questions about the Sublime Text Editor 2.

**My 1st question is,** I have several different .tmLanguage files ( ex: Console.tmLanguage) or .tmbundle (Ex: Handlebars.tmbundle) saved in the Packages/User folder. But it won't detect by the Sublime when the initial loads. If I move them under the Package folder, sublime will see them as a color syntax setting.

I thought everything should store inside the User Folder so that it won't be erased when updates or any other possible overwritten situations. **What can I do to make sublime see those file when they are stored inside User folder.**

I have moved those file several different locations. When I initialized sublime, I received this error " Error loading syntax file "Packages/User/Console.tmLanguage": Error parsing plist xml: Failed to open file In file "Packages/User/Console.tmLanguage" "

I did research about this error, one of the file maybe use that color setting has been cached. I could not remember that which one is using it. **How can I clear all the cache to get rid of this initial loading error?**

**My 2nd question is**, I am sharing the Preferences.sublime-settings file for Windows and Mac via Dropbox. But Mac has high resolution, window has not. Mac need font size of 21 to show the same size on windows( font-size: 14 ). Every time When I sync the setting, I have to switch this value from setting file. So I created two different files,  Preferences (OSX).sublime-settings and Preferences (Windows).sublime-settings to hold the font-size setting only. It seems to work on windows, but Mac just ignore that file, no font size is being applied at all. It is so tiny that I could not see. **Any ideas how could I fix that?**

Answer (score 3):

I solved the 2nd problem (i.e. eliminating display differences) as follows:

1. Create the Default folder that will "mirror" Default.sublime-package:

Window 7:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\Default
```

Mac OS X:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/Default
```

Extract two files from Default.sublime-package into this folder:

```
Preferences (OSX).sublime-settings
Preferences (Windows).sublime-settings
```

I used the following settings to get **the same** look and feel on Windows 7/XP and MacBook with Retina:

Windows:

```
{
    "font_face": "Consolas",
    "font_size": 11,
    "line_padding_top": -1
}
```

Mac OS X:

```
{
    "font_face": "Consolas",
    "font_size": 14,
    "line_padding_bottom": -1,
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1975&p=9095&hilit=overwrite%20tmlanguage#p9095) post in the Sublime Text forums, you need to remove an existing .tmlanguage file from the /Packages folder AND the .tmlanguage.cache file and relaunch Sublime Text to confirm that the program is no longer reading them. Then you can put your .tmlanguage or .tmbundle file in /Packages/User.

It's not clear to me that the error message you got was indicating a problem with the location and not a problem with the plist file itself. You might try using one of the free plist editors to make sure the structure of the file itself is OK.

Good luck on the Mac/Windows display difference. I have no idea how you might solve that.

Answer (score 0):

For windows delete - Delete all the sublime files from

C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming